# Prove inequality $|y \ln{y} - x \ln{x}| < 2 |\ln{\frac{1}{|y-x|}}|$ when $x,y \in (0,1]$, $x \neq y$.

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, logarithms, examples-counterexamples

EDIT: Counter-example found. Statement is FALSE.

However, I think the argument still has value. It is true if you restrict the domain to $[0.223,0.716]$. Maybe $[\frac{3}{10},\frac{7}{10}]$ so it’s less “obvious”?

Prove inequality $|y \ln{y} - x \ln{x}| < 2 |\ln{\frac{1}{|y-x|}}|$ , when $x,y \in (0,1]$, $x \neq y$.

Assume WLOG $y > x$.

I have tried Mean Value Theorem. For some $c \in (0,1)$:
\begin{align*}
|y \ln{y} - x \ln{x}| &= (1+\ln{c})(y-x) = (\ln(e)+\ln(c))(y-x)\\
& \leq 2 \ln{\frac{1}{(y-x)}} \text{ if and only if } \frac{(y-x)^2}{e} \leq c \leq \frac{1}{e(y-x)^2}
\end{align*}

So the inequality is true when
$$
\frac{(y-x)^2}{e} \leq x \leq y \leq \frac{1}{e(y-x)^2}
$$

in which $c$ is between $x$ and $y$. Now we need to prove for the following cases in a different way:
\begin{align*}
x < \frac{(y-x)^2}{e} &\implies x^2 - (2+e)x + 1 > 0 : \text{when 0<x<0.222ish}\\
\frac{1}{e(y-x)^2} < y &\implies y > e^{-1/3} : \text{when y > e^-1/3 = 0.716ish }
\end{align*}

as $1-x>y-x>y$. I think this statement should be true because some of the cases can be taken care by MVT, and cases where it can’t be solved by MVT are when $x$ and $y$ are near the endpoints.

I tried using taylor $\ln(1+x)$ but I can’t get anything. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's wrong. Try $x=1$ and $y=0.05.$

In this case $RHS-LHS=-0.047...<0.$

Comment: [I like it](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2*%7Cln%281%2F0.95%29%7C+-+%7C0.05*ln%280.05%29%7C). Did you hand-craft this counter-example?

Comment: @Maximilian Janisch I used WF :D After this I took a calculator and checked again because sometimes WA wrong.

Comment: Omg I feel bad for posting the question now. My lecturer gave me this question so I thought it must be right. Thanks!!!